# Validating a website in a subdomain?? 

Tags: validation, css, internet-explorer-7, subdomain

I have a website hosted under a subdomain for testing purposes and have tried to validate the html and css using w3 validator and jigsaw. Depending on the URL I use - http://alt.example.com (9 frameset type errors 4.01 Strict, CSS3 pass) OR http://www.example.com/alt (passes HTML5 / fails CSS3 183 errors, mostly vendor extensions). Why do the links validate differently and which one should I be concerned with? Any ideas on how to go about fixing them would be great.

Mystique Theme,
Mystique-Child Theme (with its own style.css using @import url for core.css),
WordPress 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the source for the alt one is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>alt.example.com</title>

</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://www.example.com/alt" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 02 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

In other words, rather than a real 301 redirect, or just being mapped to the same folder, it loads the other URL in a terrible version of an iframe. Check your hosting settings, and change it to a 301 redirect.

Comment: Rich Thank you for you reply.  I guess I was confused on which one to be concerned with, the alt.x.com or the www.x.com/alt   I have set a permanent 301 redirect and now it just sends everything to the /alt.  I guess to answer my own question, it was the www.x.com/alt that I needed to be concerned with since that is where it is being redirected.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The better option is to map it to the same folder. This would allow you to use some features available ONLY to sites hosted in the root of a domain, such as [site-root relative links](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c44a.html).

Although you *could* achieve this mapping using `.htaccess`, all major web hosting control panels have options for mapping subdomains to folders. Once you do that, you can change the direction of redirection (lol) -- its in your control. Using a subdomain is better style too.

So you can concern yourself with http://alt.example.com, and *redirect* external requests for http://www.example.com/alt to the subdomain, while internally *mapping* it to the directory /alt